# Add event to change the background color of multiple img tags

Tags: javascript

I want that when I do the mouseleave, the background of the img returns to its original color. The code I have made makes color aqua when I do the mouseleave. Why?

```
<img width="100" height="100" style="background-color:red">
<img width="100" height="100" style="background-color:bisque">
<img width="100" height="100" style="background-color:aqua">
<script>
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    var numImages = images.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < numImages; i++){

        var colorOriginal = images[i].style.backgroundColor;
        images[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
            this.style.backgroundColor = colorOriginal;
        });

        images[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'purple';
        });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: There's a typo. In the second event listener, you spelled the variable as `colcolorOriginal `

Comment: You only have one `colorOriginal` variable. You set it to red, bisque, then aqua in turn at the time you set up the event handlers.

Comment: You could do this with plain CSS and `:hover` BTW

Comment: How can I modify this code to change img backgroundColor to its original color without using css ?